# Trying to make a EFI bootable external HDD but computer just shuts down

Tags: grub2, grub, uefi

System: [HP 245 G2](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-245-g2-notebook-pc/6431925/model/6431928?sku=F7W30LT) 
OS: Debian 11 on 6.1.0-0.deb11.5-amd64 
GRUB: grub-pc (2.06-3~deb11u5), grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.06-3~deb11u5). 
Drive: WDC WD5000LPVX-22V0TT0 (01.01A01) with a GUID Partition Table, connected through USB 2.0 using a SABRENT SATA to USB 3 chassis (ID 2109:0715 VIA Labs, Inc. VL817 SATA Adaptor) *. . (I'm using it on USB 2 since my system can't boot USB 3)*

**Setup** 
I have an external HDD with Debian 11 and a NTFS partition on it, the disk is GPT formatted and has both a grub_bios and a ESP partition.
[image: GParted showing a /dev/sdb storage device with 465.76 GiB of total space, it has 5 partitions. The first partition is /dev/sdb4 located at the start of the disk, it is 702 MiB big and is a grub2 core.img File System, it has the bios_grub flag. The second partition has the name of "EFI System Partition" and has a fat32 file system, it is 702 MiB and has 695.11 MiB free, it has the boot and esp flags.]
I installed grub-pc using `sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot /dev/sdb` (used --uefi-secure-boot accidentally as I was trying to install a EFI boot, but it works) and I installed grub-efi-amd64-bin using `sudo grub-install --removable --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdb` and `sudo grub-install --removable --target=x86_64-efi-signed --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Debian --uefi-secure-boot` (ESP was mounted to /boot/efi).
To add more context, I have the GRUB menu active, so it doesn't instantly boot to Debian. and I do have Reboot and Shutdown options on the GRUB menu but the shutdown option is also default, which is not what my computer is doing.
Below is what the EFI partition contains

```
root@xproot-hdd:/boot/efi# ls --color=auto
EFI
root@xproot-hdd:/boot/efi# cd EFI
root@xproot-hdd:/boot/efi/EFI# ls --color=auto
BOOT
root@xproot-hdd:/boot/efi/EFI# cd BOOT
root@xproot-hdd:/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT# ls --color=auto
BOOTX64.CSV  BOOTX64.EFI  fbx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi
root@xproot-hdd:/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT# file *
BOOTX64.CSV: data
BOOTX64.EFI: PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
fbx64.efi:   PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
grub.cfg:    ASCII text
grubx64.efi: PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
mmx64.efi:   PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
root@xproot-hdd:/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT# cat grub.cfg
search.fs_uuid 8fb383e6-30ee-4a55-90e9-64240f6cab7f root hd1,gpt3 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

**The Problem** 
The BIOS boot works as I've tested it on two computers without any major problems. The EFI boot on the other hand just restarts the computer, I know it is trying to read as the HDD activity light blinks but it just doesn't work. I have not ruled out the possibility of my current computer not playing nice as I do not own other UEFI-capable computers.

Edit: I just tested a Lenovo Ideapad 330 and same thing occurs.

Comment: Are you trying to have both BIOS boot and UEFI boot with same drive? Some have made it work, but updates may get grub out of sync and then you have issues. UEFI boot uses /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi for external drives. That is created with the removable entry in grub, but I do not think that creates a grub.cfg which may need to be in /EFI/grub. Not sure with Debian as I use Ubuntu.

Comment: @oldfred I ended up using rEFInd which can boot Linux, surprisingly after I installed rEFInd GRUB booted (ofc when booting it through rEFInd).